# Should NVDA browse mode focus make navigation focus to move?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, nvda

I am getting familiar with NVDA screen reader. I discovered users use nvda "Browse mode" to explore and navigate through web pages. In some examples when I use arrow keys in the browse mode to navigate through the page, main navigation focus stays at the focusable html element it was at the very beginning. But on on my project the navigation focus sometimes moves to control I am currently exploring with arrow keys in the browse mode. So, should the navigation focus stay in place while arrows are used in the browse mode, or they should move to focusable elements which are being explored?

Answer (score 3):

#### General answer

In general, you shouldn't assume anything.
As you will see below in specific answers, there are different approaches in making webpages accessible, readable and navigable with a screen reader.

The system focus may follow the browse cursor, or may not, depending at least on:

- the exact HTML, DOM tree, accessibility tree
- user settings
- screen reader used
- browser used
- OS used

Even if Jaws and NVDA have a well known way to work and even if it appears to be the most common, you shouldn't assume anything, and shouldn't rely on that specific functionning.
By doing so, you are going to create problems for people out of the target systems/browsers/screen readers, unless, of course, if you have such a specific target and if you are sure that no one will run outside of it.
Jaws and NVDA aren't the only existing screen readers under windows, and windows isn't the only existing OS.

#### Specific answer for Jaws and NVDA

Typically, the system focus follows the focus/form/PC cursor, but not the browse/document/virtual cursor.
This implies that the system focus only moves when switching to the former, as long as it stays active.
But **be aware, this isn't an absolute rule**, and we assume that **you aren't using the application role** for which rules are different.

The main thing to understand is which cursor is used when, and especially when switches occurr. There are three main possibilities:

- Switching cursor on user's demand, i.e.  pressing NVDA+Space, JawsKey+Numpad+, escape, enter on a form field, etc.
- When pressing tab or shift+tab, the next or previous focusable element is determined based on the browse cursor position, but the form cursor is (at least shortly) switched to in order to move the system focus accordingly
- When navigating with the browse cursor, the form cursor may be switched to automatically or not, depending on configuration and kind of navigation used

For the third point, Jaws has for example the setting auto form mode, with three options:

- manual mode, where it never switch from virtual to PC cursor automatically
- auto mode, where PC cursor is automatically switched on and off when landing on and out a form field, when navigating with tab as well as arrow keys
- Semi-auto mode, when switch occurs only when landing on form fields while pressing tab and shift+tab but not arrow keys

The default settings of NVDA is mostly the auto mode of Jaws.

This most certainly explain why you notice that sometimes the system focus is moved: you pressed down arrow and landed on a form field, causing an automatic switch to form mode to occur.
Pressing again down arrow make you switch again to the browse mode, leaving the system focus at its last place.
If you did it rapidely, you effectively could have noticed a system focus move that you found surprising, without noticing the cursor switches.

One final note: the most recent versions of Jaws and NVDA include an option to visually show where is the browse cursor, for example with a green rectangle.
Don't be confused, these visual indications have nothing to do with system focus. These visual indications are only relevant for partially sighted people or those who want to understand better how navigation with the virtual cursor works.

#### Specific answer for VoiceOver and others

I don't know VoiceOver as well as Jaws and NVDA, but the rules that cause system focus to move are different, as VoiceOver way of navigating into web contents is also quite different from Jaws and NVDA.

As far as my experience goes, navigation with VO shortcuts behave mostly like the browse mode of Jaws and NVDA: the system focus doesn't move by default.
The system focus is moved only when beginning an interaction implicitely or explicitely, i.e. when double-taping, clicking, pressing tab/shift+tab, etc.
Please correct me in comments and I will update the answer.

Also as far as I know, Orca under linux has a quite similar way of working than Jaws and NVDA.

I don't know at all how it works with Talkback under Android.

It would be interesting that experts of the respective other platforms come and  post a similar answer as above for their systems/screen readers.

Comment: The answer is weird. I asked quite concrete question about concrete screen reader. You answered like a bot.

Comment: I prefer giving a general answer, in case someone else ask the same question for another screen reader tomorrow, and I'm trying to explain what's going on with cursors as it is often misunderstood. But since I'm a bot, anyway, I'm going do delete that soon. Too bad. I'm happy to have wasted my time.

Comment: @QuentunC, no offence but it is not very easy to understand the answer. Also I have no idea what is form mode. I am familiar only with browse and focus nvda modes

Comment: I guess forms mode is the same as focus mode. If yes then the system focus (or navigation focus as it is said in specification) is moved to control without nvda switching from browse mode to focus mode - I've been tracking whether these modes switch

Comment: Form, focus or PC cursor is indeed the same. It's the cursor used to interact with form controls. Browse, document or virtual cursor is the same, it is used to read through the page.

Comment: The linked article here describes forms/focus mode and browse/document mode. https://tink.uk/understanding-screen-reader-interaction-modes/ It's a very important distinction, which came as a big surprise to me when I started getting into accessibility. In particular, you need to be clear which semantic roles (in your markup) trigger which kind of interaction. BTW Quentin, your 'bot' answer is entirely appropriate for this rather nuanced topic. (I don't think it's bot-like).

Comment: Yes, appropriate and thorough answer. Really helped me understand these modes and how the various readers deal with them.